# Getting exception when using linq

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

It's not duplicate of this question([How to do multiple joins when using groupby in linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053489/how-to-do-multiple-joins-when-using-groupby-in-linq)), situation has changed.

I have a picture rating table in my database. For every new rating, a new picture rating table row will be created. I am grouping those ratings by lastweek and pictureid, meaning all the ratings for one single pic in the last week will be accumulated and become one rating.Then i will be able to sort them by their count. Then I am joining two other tables two show user and picture related details.

This is my code :

```
public IQueryable<SortedDto> GetOne()
{
        var pastDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1);
        var combo = from l in db.picturerating
                    where l.iddatetime > pastDate
                    group l by l.idpictures into pgroup
                    let count = pgroup.Count()
                    orderby count descending
                    join p in db.picturedetails on pgroup.FirstOrDefault().idpictures equals p.idpictures  into first
                    join u in db.users on pgroup.FirstOrDefault().iduser equals u.iduser into second    
                    select new SortedDto
                    {
                        IdPictures = pgroup.FirstOrDefault().idpictures,
                        IdUser = pgroup.FirstOrDefault().iduser,
                        IdDatetime = first.FirstOrDefault().pictime,
                        totalrating = pgroup.Average(l => (float?)l.rating) ?? 0, sex =second.FirstOrDefault().sex,
                        username =second.FirstOrDefault().username,
                        dob = second.FirstOrDefault().dob

                    };

    return combo;
}
```

When running this code I get an exception like this :

> InnerException: {
>   Message: "An error has occurred.",
>   ExceptionMessage: "Unknown column 'Apply1.idpictures' in 'where clause'",
>   ExceptionType: "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException"
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId) 
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId) 
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult() 
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) 
>          at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) 
>          at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)

So why am I getting this exception? Any thing wrong with my linq query?

Comment: See if you have case sensitivity on in MySql. Set a break point on the return statement and grab the query, then run it direct on the db and you'll be able to fix it from there

Comment: Okay but is my query's logic right? Can joins be done this way

Comment: Unknown Column Apply1.idpictures...Means the name doesnt match your DB...IS your DB Column Plural like that? If not, then you need to remove pluralizing naming convention.

Comment: All other linq queries are working fine, i think its something wrong with my query

Comment: Just try simplifying the query until you narrow it down. Linq Pad is a good tool for testing Linq queries, it's free to download.

Comment: Its mysql database so linqpad wont help.

Comment: Are you using a database model?

Comment: I am using database first approach